# How do I add a Ethernet and a WiFi connection to a single Link Aggregate?

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, router, lan

I have two different ways of connecting to my NAS, one WiFi, and one Ethernet connection. How do I add both of them to a Link Aggregate connection in macOS? The menu only shows the Ethernet connection as an option for creating a Link Aggregate right now.

This is not about two internet connections, but two connections within my local network in which I have full control over the router. I'd like to be able to connect to my NAS faster using both connections. Is this possible?

Comment: This is probably not possible, but depends on your hardware.  What NAS do you have?

Comment: I have a Synology DS218j NAS which only has one LAN port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not really possible. As the NAS only has a single port you are not going to get faster then Ethernet speed, so there is no point in attempting to channel bond to get faster speed - you are limite to gigabit.

Adding WIFI, even if it can technically be done, will have the affect of slowing the NAS down because WIFI  has higher latency and is a less stable connection the Ethernet - that means that any channel binding you do will have to take into account WIFI variability and likely not going to perform.

If you are finding things slow, and you don't already, try getting a gigabit switch and plugging both the Mac and NAS into the switch, and the switch into the router.  Very often routers acting as switches are slow and using a dedicated switch can greatly boost performance.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. The ethernet connection between my computer and the router/NAS setup is slow since it's currently going through a 100MBit switch and a powerlan adapter. But I guess I'll just try it with a faster switch.

Comment: Ouch. Upgrading the switch to a gigabit one could help, but the powerline adaptors still will be a bottleneck. What speed is the adaptor rated at, and what speeds do you get for file transfers? Also, how difficult/expensive/doable is running an Ethernet cable, what model router do you have, what WIFI card does your Mac have and am I correct in understanding the NAS and router are plugged into the switch and the power line connects the Mac? Also, how many WIFI channels from others do you see?

Comment: (I partially solved a similar problem before the wireless AC standard came ubiquitous by setting up a dedicated 802.11a backhaul between my TV and the rest of of my network while running 802.11n for everything else. Boosted my speed from 100 megabit to about 300 megabit. You may be able to achieve better by using 2 $$$ router/APs but it may be cheaper to run an Ethernet cable!

Comment: I'd get about 330Mbit on the powerlan if the switch wasn't so slow. My WiFi is at around 200Mbit for 2,4GHz (I have an expensive PCIe WiFi card with 3 antennas since I'm pretty far away from the router which serves as the closest AP) and 350Mbit with 5Ghz but that drops out regularly. My router might also be the culprit in being apparently bad at WiFi. I'm getting a gigabit switch tomorrow. I'll probably settle with Ethernet as primary and WiFi as a "seamless" fallback in case the powerlan drops out, which it does regularly. Although that might cause problems since it's different IPs.

Comment: Its probably overkill for your requirements, but if you have problems with IP changes you may be able to run OpenVPN between your laptop and DiS218j which may be able to reduce issues with IP address changes (as it virtualizes an interface you can use instead)